# Redirect 301 whole domain together with some specific URL's

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have two domains:
newdomain.com 
and
olddomain.com

I need to redirect all links from olddomain.com to the main page of newdomain.com so it should look like this:

```
olddomain.com/irrelevantDir1/irrelevantPage1.html -> newdomain.com

olddomain.com/irrelevantDir11/irrelevantPage11.html -> newdomain.com
```

But there are some links that i want to save:

```
olddomain.com/relevantDir1/relevantPage1.html -> newdomain.com/newRelevantDir1/newRelevantPage1.html

olddomain.com/relevantDir11/relevantPage11.html -> newdomain.com/newRelevantDir11/newRelevantPage11.html
```

I already spent two days tried to make RewriteRule but with no luck, i can really use some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your rules from specific to general case handling like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# specific URL redirect 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^relevantDir1/relevantPage1\.html$ http://newdomain.com/newRelevantDir1/newRelevantPage1.html [NC,L,R=301]

# specific URL redirect 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^relevantDir11/relevantPage11\.html$ http://newdomain.com/newRelevantDir11/newRelevantPage11.html [NC,L,R=301]

# generic case
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It comes out that i had the right solution long time ago, source of my problem was my web browser, at incognito mode it keeps the old redirection. Thanks a lot !